# Python connect to a C++ dll after it's initialized by a host program?

Tags: c++, python, c, dll

The host program supports C++ plugin. The C++ dll is written as its plugin. The plugin will be initialized by the host program on startup.
Is there any way to use Python to attach to the C++ dll **after** it's initialized by the host?
The intention is to offload all the heavy work to Python since it's a familiar language.

Based on my search, there is ctypes, can ctypes achieve that?  Or do I have to embed a python interpreter inside the C++ dll?

Comment: connect to the c++ dll as you would any other application, IPC... tcp, local shared memory, pipelines etc...

Comment: Is there a way to expose the C++ dll to python so there is minimal communication overhead? I guess 'connect' is too generic.

Comment: `ctypes` allows Python to load a DLL and call functions.  If the goal is to implement much of the plugin functionality in Python, then either embed a python interpreter inside the plugin, or communicate with an external interpreter via IPC.

Comment: you can directly load a DLL with `ctypes`. This isn't what you're asking for though, you want to gain direct access to the c++ functions after its already been loaded by another program. The only way to do that is for there to be some sort of IPC setup to talk back and forth with your DLL through your host application.

Comment: What is this *host* you are talking about ? Is it something rather well known like a Java JNI invocation ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a C++ plugin, then delegate the functionality to your Python code (embeeded in the plugin or on the filesystem) with [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).

But you will have to write a good deal of C++ code anyway. And it won't be the easy kind to debug. You will have to bridge the C++ to Python memory management with the one used by your plug-in architecture.

Might as well bite the bullet and write the plugin in C++. Community support is also something to consider. You probably don't want to be the only one with this architecture.